# Using vue-cli-service with typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I have a Vue project that I created with the Vue CLI, and I now want to enable TypeScript on the project. I took a look at [this guide](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Vue-Starter#adding-webpack), but it recommends adding a Webpack config and replacing `vue-cli-service` in the `package.json` scripts section with Webpack.

Is there any way I can continue to use `vue-cli-service` to build my Vue app and enable TypeScript support for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up generating a new vue project using vue cli with typescript enabled and copied the tsconfig and added the packages missing in my package.json

Answer (score 1):

With an existing Vue CLI project, you can add TypeScript support by entering this command:

```sh
vue add typescript
```

Beware that this command will overwrite files, but you can use `git diff` to view the differences.

Answer (score 0):

In vue-cli 3.x

```
$ vue create <app_name>
```

This will bring up a prompt, select `Manually select features`, enable `TypeScript` using the space bar. It will automatically configure everything for you.

Comment: This is an existing app though. Is there any way to change the settings after setup?